# Is water actually blue or is it transparent?

Tags: water

This is my first post on StackExchange and I would like to ask a question:
Is water actually blue or is that just the reflection of the sky?

Answer (score 6):

It is blue. But white light needs to cross a long distance through the water to actually get the blue tint.

[This related question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/13240/11908) explains it for ice, but for water it is pretty much the same story.

[This article](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/why-does-the-ocean-appear/), mentioned by [@JeopardyTempest](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users/6298/jeopardytempest) in the comments of the answer to the above question, tackles the case of the oceans. There it says:

> The ocean looks blue because red, orange and yellow (long wavelength
>   light) are absorbed more strongly by water than is blue (short
>   wavelength light). So when white light from the sun enters the ocean,
>   it is mostly the blue that gets returned.